# split child elements into sub sections

Tags: xslt

Given the following XML

```
<section>
    <title>Title1</title>
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
    <title>Title2</title>
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
</section>
```

What is the easiest way to split at second title into this

```
<section>
    <subsection>
        <title>Title1</title>
        <item>Item1</item>
        <item>Item2</item>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
        <title>Title2</title>
        <item>Item1</item>
        <item>Item2</item>
    </subsection>
</section>
```

for example the following template was one idea but the xpath seems tricky.

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:copy>
         <subsection>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="...those before second title..."/>
         </subsection>
         <subsection>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="...those including and after second title..."/>
         </subsection>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 or later it's a straightforward use of `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="title">
             <subsection>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
             </subsection>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In 1.0 you can achieve a similar effect with this kind of logic:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="title">
             <subsection>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::item[
                                  generate-id(preceding-sibling::title[1])
                                = generate-id(current())]"/>
             </subsection>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The predicate finds those following sibling `item` elements of the current `title` whose nearest preceding `title` is the one we started from.

One difference between the two approaches is if you have any other elements in a `section` before the *first* `title`, then the `for-each-group` approach will put them in a leading subsection (which will have no title), whereas the 1.0 approach will ignore them.

---

If you always want *exactly two* subsections (with everything after the second `title` in the second subsection, including any further `title` elements) then you can just hard-code it as

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:copy>
         <subsection>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="title[2]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
         </subsection>
         <subsection>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="title[2] | title[2]/following-sibling::*"/>
         </subsection>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note that if there are fewer than two `title` elements this will result in two completely empty `<subsection/>` elements)